# Validate select list with react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I want to implement validation for React form using `react-hook-form`. For input value I implemented this:

```
       <div className='input-group mb-3'>
          <Controller
              control={control}
              name={"email"} //  the key of json
              defaultValue={""}
              render={({ field }) => (
                  <input
                      {...field}
                      type="email"
                      className="form-control"
                      placeholder="Email"
                      aria-label="email"
                      onChange={(e) => field.onChange(e.target.value)}
                  />
              )}
          />
        </div>
```

For me it's not clear how I need to implement it for select menu:

```
            <div className='input-group mb-3'>
              <select
                className='form-control form-select'
                name='budget'
                id='budget'
                required=''
                data-msg='Please select your budget.'
              >
                <option value=''>Budget</option>                  
                <option value='budget3'>More than $500,000</option>
              </select>
            </div>
```

Wat is the proper way to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

somethings like this works?

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="budget"
  rules={{
    budget: {
      required: "Required",
    },
  }}
  render={({ field }) => (
    <select name="budget" onChange={field.onChange} value={field.value}>
      <option value="">Please select your budget</option>
      <option value="budget3">More than $500,000</option>
      <option value="budget2">$250,000 - $500,000</option>
      <option value="budget1">$100,000 - $250,000</option>
      {/* more budgets */}
    </select>
  )}
/>;
```

`control` is destructured from `useForm` like so:

```
const { controls, register, setValue, ...moreEls } = useForm();
```

Comment: Thanks, the code is working but there is no validation message. I opened a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73351493/implement-validation-message-for-react-hook-form Can you advise please?

Comment: You can destructure `errors` from `useForm` and display the `errors.budget?.message`  somewhere in a DOM element like `<label>{errors.budget?.message}</label>`