# Implement validation message for react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I ant to implement a form with `react-hook-form`. I tried this:

```
....
 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className='mt-4 register-form'>
            <div className='row'>
              <div className='col-sm-6'>
                <div className='input-group mb-3'>
                  <Controller
                      control={control}
                      name={"name"} //  the key of json
                      defaultValue={""}
                      render={({ field }) => (
                          <input
                              {...field}
                              type="text"
                              className="form-control"
                              placeholder="Name"
                              aria-label="name"
                              onChange={(e) => field.onChange(e.target.value)}
                          />
                      )}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
.....
```

Full page code:

https://pastebin.com/KZzsLZAn

When I submit the form I send a POST message using:

```
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";

const baseURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

export const SubmitContact = (json) => {
    return axios.post(baseURL, json);
};
```

But there is no validation message into the form and no final message that the form is successfully summitted.

Do you know how I can implement this functionality?

Comment: Adding validation: https://react-hook-form.com/get-started/#Applyvalidation checking if sent successfully: if `setPost` in your `onSubmit` is reached, sending the data worked (also note that you called the parameter `json` but it's an object, not json; json is a text format that looks like a JS object literal) (also the initial value of `post` should be `{}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting the `errors` from `useForm` like so:

```
const { errors, ...rest } = useForm();

<div className="col-sm-6">
  <div className="input-group mb-3">
    <Controller
      control={control}
      name={"name"} //  the key of json
      defaultValue={""}
      rules={{ required: true }}
      render={({ field }) => (
        <input
          {...field}
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Name"
          aria-label="name"
          onChange={(e) => field.onChange(e.target.value)}
        />
      )}
    />
    {errors.name && (
      <div className="alert alert-danger">{errors.name.message}</div>
    )}
  </div>
</div>;
```

Comment: I have one additional question: When I submit the form, fields into the form are not cleared. Any idea why?

Comment: Well that's normal. Inputs are not meant to be cleared after `onSubmit` — with errors. What gets cleared are any possible `errors` while they are solved by the user.

Comment: Do you know how I can implement it?

Comment: I tried the code but I get `ContactsForm.js:45 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')`

Comment: Please change `name={name}` key from something else, I dunno if it's a reserver word.

Comment: Rules are not defined correctly here

Answer (score 1):

To display error message:

```
const { control, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();

...

<form onSubmit="{handleSubmit(onSubmit)}" className="mt-4 register-form">
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col-sm-6">
      <div className="input-group mb-3">
        <Controller 
          control={control} 
          name="name"
          defaultValue="" 
          rules={{ required: true }}
          render={({ field }) => ( 
            <input 
             {...field} 
             type="text"
             className="form-control" 
             placeholder="Name" 
             aria-label="name"
             onChange={(e) => field.onChange(e.target.value)} 
            /> 
           )} 
         />
         {errors.name && <p>{errors.name.message}</p>}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

To reset the form after submission:

```
const { control, reset, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();

...

const onSubmit = (formData) => {
    try {
      SubmitContact(formData).then((res) => {
        setPost(res.data);
        reset();
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
};
```

Comment: you need to define rules as well

Comment: What kind of rules are you talking about? @YashJoshi

Comment: when you use the controller you need to define rules in order to show an error message, as of now it doesn't have any. Also, we get errors in `formState` now, Ref: https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/formstate

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `rules` correctly in `Controller` component, you don't need to define the name of registered input, you just have to say rules:

```
rules={{ 
   required: "Required", // Note you are wrapping this inside a key which is not required
}}
```

To access this error messages, you need to use `formState` from `useForm`

```
const {formState: {errors}} = useForm()

// accessing errors
{errors.country?.message}
```

In order to clear form just use `reset`

Here's a working sandbox of your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/late-haze-jivrwp?file=/src/App.js

On submit you can see the error popping up on country field